# Are those buttons created in CSS or another script?

Tags: css, button

I'm really new at coding and I would like to know if you guys could tell me if this kind of button is created with CSS or anyother language!  Here is the design I want to create:

[image: Here is the design]

Basicaly what I want to create is a set of X options in a column.

When you put your mouse over the button, the lenght (and maybe color) of the button would change and if there is other options to choose from, another set of buttons would appear!

I would like to know how it is created and if you guys could give me some ideas or a link on how to build this I would be eternally grateful!  I've already surfed the net but I can't find what I want!

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking for the `:hover` selector? How to make CSS triangles?

Comment: Those buttons can be created any number of ways, including css. Did you create that image or is from an existing site? If it from an existing site, provide the original url or just look at the source code yourself and see how it was made.

Comment: If you're using AngularJs you can use its directive ngMouseOver to detect the mouse is over a particular element and then just do a on-click="handleMouseOverEvent()" inside that element and then handle the .css styel inside the "handleMouseOverEvent()" method.

Comment: @SLaks, I don't know how to create triangles with CSS and I don't know how to create the sub options with CSS.

Comment: @Grice, No I created this image using PHOTOSHOP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by creating triangles on `:before` and `:after` :pseudo-elements. And the rest is pretty much basic HTML and CSS.

For some reason, Chrome renders the `ul`s off by 4px. For that, I've added JavaScript code to detect if the browser is chrome and if it is then loop through the stylesheet, find the rule for `ul` and change its `top` value.

### EDIT: [Tweaked demo on Codepen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/QwNGMW/)

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1) {
  var ss = document.styleSheets;
  for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
    var rules = ss[i];
    for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
      var r = rules.cssRules[j];
      if (r.selectorText == "ul") {
        r.style.top = '-16px';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.btn-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 288px;
}
.btn-container:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in, background-color 0.2s ease-in;
  z-index: 9;
}
.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  right: -50px;
  border-left: 50px solid black;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border-left-color 0.2s ease-in;
}
ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 129px;
  list-style: none;
  transition: left 0.2s ease-in;
}
.sub-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in;
}
.sub-button:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.sub-button:first-child:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: -100px;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid gray;
  transition: border-right-color 0.2s ease-in;
}
.btn-container:hover > .btn {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: red;
}
.btn-container:hover > .btn:after {
  border-left-color: red;
}
.btn-container:hover > .btn + .sub-button-container > ul {
  left: 159px;
}
.btn-container:hover > .btn + .sub-button-container > ul .sub-button {
  display: block;
}
.btn-container:hover > .btn + .sub-button-container > ul .sub-button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.btn-container:hover > .btn + .sub-button-container > ul .sub-button:hover:before {
  border-right-color: red;
}
ul:first-child {
  z-index: 0;
}
ul:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 1;
}
ul:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 2;
}
ul:last-child {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn">OPTION 1</div>
    <div class="sub-button-container">
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 1.1</li>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 1.2</li>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 1.3</li>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 1.4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn">OPTION 2</div>
    <div class="sub-button-container">
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 2.1</li>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 2.2</li>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 2.3</li>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 2.4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn">OPTION 3</div>
    <div class="sub-button-container">
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 3.1</li>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 3.2</li>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 3.3</li>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 3.4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn">OPTION 4</div>
    <div class="sub-button-container">
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 4.1</li>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 4.2</li>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 4.3</li>
        <li class="sub-button">OPTION 4.4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whoops! Forgot the animation, be back with it when its ready.

Comment: Whoah! I just don't understand everything in here but I will sure study that!  I ran the snippet and it's exactly what I want!  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way I could contact you privatly so I could ask you some questions regarding your code?  I don't see anyway to PM you here!

Comment: @Konsume - Okay! I'll create a chat room.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AngularJs you can use its directive ngMouseOver to detect the mouse is over a particular element and then just do a on-click="handleMouseOverEvent()" inside that element and then handle the .css styel inside the "handleMouseOverEvent()" method.

Comment: Thanks for helping, unfortunatly this was chinese to me!  Is there a tutorial you could think of that could help me?

Comment: Yeah, they do exist. I'm not certain of a particular one but it sounds to me like you just need basic language logic under your belt. Which, can be found in nearly any beginners book of that particular language. Also, if you liked my answer don't forget to up/like it (+1).

Answer (score 1):

well, if you picked up this from a website, you can toggle developer mode by pressing f12 and read the code yourself, and you can acctually make a similar style with CSS, but for the interactive part of displaying options you'll need javascript

Comment: Thanks for helping, unfortunatly I created this image using photoshop to better describe my needs! =X

Comment: it would help if you started looking at projects, or demos of menus, since what you are describing here sounds to me like some sort of vertial menu with jquery, he's some code of a basic menu http://cssdeck.com/labs/g7zjeees

Comment: No need for JavaScript here. This could be easily done with CSS alone.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with CSS in so many ways. E.g with CSS skew method-See one example below

**HTML**

```
<table width="400" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td> <span> Option 1 </span></td>
      <td>Option 1.1</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
}

td:first-of-type  {
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-50deg);
   -moz-transform: skewX(-50deg);
   -ms-transform: skewX(-50deg);
   -o-transform: skewX(-50deg);
   transform: skewX(-50deg);
   padding-left: 60px;
   margin-right: -20px;
   margin-left: -15px;
}

td:first-of-type span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(50deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(50deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(50deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(50deg);
    transform: skewX(50deg);
    padding-left: 60px;
        margin-right: -50px;

}

td:last-of-type {
    background-color: green;
     padding-left: 50px;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

[See working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/euwe9rr7/)

**Note:** This example was just put together quickly, so you can play around with it a little more until you achieve what you want. It can also be achieved with **lists**